# Cannot convert return expression of type Object<String> to return type Object<Character>

Tags: swift

I am working with some piece of code found in `Functional programming in Swift`, but the book is not updated with Swift 2, and I am getting on error in the following code:

```
func insert<T: Hashable>(key: [T], trie: Trie<T>) -> Trie<T> {
    if let (head, tail) = key.decompose {
        if let nextTrie = trie.children[head] {
            var newChildren = trie.children
            newChildren[head] = insert(tail, trie: nextTrie)

            return Trie(isElem: trie.isElem, children: newChildren)
        } else {
            var newChildren = trie.children
            newChildren[head] = single(tail)

            return Trie(isElem: trie.isElem, children: newChildren)
        }
    } else {
        return Trie(isElem: true, children: trie.children)
    }
}

func buildString(words: [String]) -> Trie<Character> {
    return reduce(words, empty()) { trie, word in
        insert([word], trie: trie)
    }
}
```

Inside `buildString` I get this:

```
Cannot convert return expression of type Trie<String>  to return type Trie<Character>
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Is that the original code or did you already try to change it?

Comment: The call to `insert` doesn't match it's signature. You're calling with `[String], Trie<Character>` while the signature expects `[T], Trie<T>`.

Comment: the original code is: insert(Array(word), trie: trie)...but it says I need to add arrayLiteral in front of word, so its the same as [word].

Comment: I also tried [word.characters] but then it says: "T is not inferred" error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `empty` looks like this

```
func empty<T>() -> Trie<T> {
    return Trie<T>()
}
```

change the `buildString` function to

```
func buildString(words: [String]) -> Trie<Character> {
    return words.reduce(empty()) { trie, word in
        insert(Array(word.characters), trie: trie)
    }
}
```

#### Explanation

What you want in the first argument of `insert` is an array of `Character` instances which you get by calling `Array(word.characters)`. `Array(word)` is the Swift 1.2 way and doesn't work in Swift 2 anymore. In addition, `[word.characters]` just creates an array with a single element (the string's character view) which is why it doesn't work as well.

Note that I also changed the global `reduce` function (Swift 1.2 way) to the instance method `.reduce` (Swift 2 way).